How to find the field for a criterion in Odoo Mailing List?
I want to add a criterion to a Mailing List in Odoo, but I can’t find the field to check for. The field is named Pricelist. I type "Price...", but it doesn't appear in the drop-down menu. Meanwhile, I'm able to add other fields to the criteria. The mailing list filters individual contacts according to the criteria.

The settings of the field in Studio mode for a company:

And this is the look for an individual:

When I try to search for the field Parent Company -> Pricelist or Related Company -> Pricelist in the criterion drop-down menu, I can’t find it either. I found several similar
topics on the odoo.com forum, but I'm not sure they can help in this case. This is Odoo version 15.0+e
What should I do to make the field Pricelist appear in the criterion drop-down menu interface the same way as, for instance, Delivery Method appears there?

The reason it can't be found: the field property_product_pricelist is not stored in database as simple many2one field (foreign key) but as property field (used in multi tenant feature of odoo). Usually you can use property fields in searches/domains, e.g. property_account_payable_id can be found. But Odoo decided to make the pricelist computed and not stored in res_partner table. So it can't be used in searches/domains.
